# System Exception, no installed component detected

Tags: c#, exception

I've started learning C# and this is my first exercise. I am getting a `System.Exception`. I don't know what it is, also Visual Studio 2013 is saying that the component is not installed. I have checked the code for syntax errors.

```
private void startButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    AddEnemy();
}

private void AddEnemy()
{
    ContentControl enemy = new ContentControl();
    enemy.Template = Resources["EnemyTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
    AnimateEnemy(enemy, 0, playArea.ActualWidth - 100, "(Canvas.Left)");
    AnimateEnemy(enemy, random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100), random.Next((int)playArea.ActualHeight - 100), "Canvas.Top");
    playArea.Children.Add(enemy);
}

private void AnimateEnemy(ContentControl enemy, double from, double to, string propertyToAnimate)
{
    Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard() { AutoReverse = true, RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever };
    DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation()
    {
        From = from,
        To = to,
        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(random.Next(4, 6)))
    };
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, enemy);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, propertyToAnimate);
    storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

Comment: If you are new to programming and C#, then this is really **way** to complicated as a first exercise. Stick to a good book or tutorial.

Comment: I am using Head First C# 3rd edition and its just a copy paste exercise from the book but its not working for me :|

Comment: Talha, you need to be a bit more specific in your question - where are you getting System.Exception - on which line ? Do you know what the code is supposed to do ? Do you know what a System.Exception is ? Which component is VS.net 2013 saying is "not installed". 

We're not going to pick up your code and paste it into our VS.net to see where it crashes for you - you need to do a bit more work first in order to ask a question which has a definite answer. Glad to see you are learning C# and look forward to a bit more detail on your question.

Comment: Wow! It really is the first exercise. This book jumps too quickly into advanced topics for someone who is new to programming. http://www.amazon.co.uk/Head-First-C-Jennifer-Greene/dp/1449343503/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1416060386&sr=8-1&keywords=head+first+c%23 (Click on "Look Inside" to see this exercise in full)

Comment: @TalhaMalik This is a *first* exercise for programming C#? Holy... get another book ASAP.

Comment: Ok! Can you guys please recommend me good books to learn C# . I chose this book because it also gives an overview about window application development. I don't want to learn something which is not used in present.

Comment: @PhillipH Its a game when i press start button then red circles should start bouncing on the screen! but when the application starts it gives an error of unhanded exception in the code which is generated by the VS.net 2013 and breaks the code the IDE directs me to the if statement below
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif

Comment: Also one the side it says the following:
Exception:Thrown: "No installed components were detected.

Cannot resolve TargetProperty Canvas.Top on specified object." (System.Exception)
A System.Exception was thrown: "No installed components were detected.

Cannot resolve TargetProperty Canvas.Top on specified object."
WinRT information: Cannot resolve TargetProperty Canvas.Top on specified object.
Time: 11/15/2014 8:51:57 PM
Thread:<No Name>[3392]

Comment: Dont buy a book use the free resources ; Microsoft do an excellent free technical academy http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/ which has lots of online C# courses - I'd particularly recommend http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/c-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners

Comment: Thanks! I will follow these :)